# How to remove � at the end of a substr string?

Tags: php, string, substring

how can I remove this char `�` that is produced at the end of my substr string?

Comment: Do you know the numerical value of that character?

Comment: what? who? where.. we need more info... what string are you trying to substr, how do you use substr, is it utf-8? unicode? other?

Comment: @fingerman, see Headshota's answer (and my comment). Obvious, once one knows about that important �.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using mb_substr instead of substr

[mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Comment: Correct. The � is [Unicode U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), specified as: *used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode*. So, `substr` was erroneously used on a Unicode string.

Answer (score 0):

is it always there?  then maybe do an additional -1 from the length when you take the substring...

Comment: No, it's not always there, it appears on some strings with no remarkable difference

Answer (score 0):

This will remove last char from `$mystr`.

```
$newstr = substr($mystr, 0, -1);
```